# queue up promises while using them in setters

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, lodash

I'm trying to iterate through an array and set one property of each element using an asynchronous function. I want to return this entire thing as one Promise. What's a good way to queue up all these promises? (I can import a NodeJS library if needed.)

The code basically looks like this:

```
.then(articles => {
    articles.forEach(article => {
      article.content = someAsyncFunction();
    });
    // How do I queue up and return each of these promises?
})
.then(() => { /* other stuff... */ })
```

Comment: [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)?

Comment: Do you really need a sequential *queue*, or just something that waits for all results and can be chained?

Comment: why do you use `.map` when you don't care about the result of `.map` and the function inside doesn't return anything? A `.map` used like that has a name ... `.forEach`

Comment: Sorry @Jaramonda, It was supposed to say `forEach`, I've updated that. And no, `Promise.all()` clearly does not work in this case; I'm asking how to return a list of promises from the `forEach`

Answer (score 0):

Use promise.all. js fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rohitanand/fdkt16L2/

```js
function createPromise(value,aftertime){
 return new Promise(function(resolve){
   setTimeout(function(){
     resolve(value);
    },aftertime)
  })
}
var abc = Promise.resolve({a:1,b:2,c:3})
.then(function(value){
 var promisearr =[];
  promisearr.push(createPromise(5,1000).then(function(val){ value.a = val;}));
   promisearr.push(createPromise(10,2000).then(function(val){ value.b = val;}));
    promisearr.push(createPromise(15,3000).then(function(val){ value.c = val;}));
    return Promise.all(promisearr).then(function(){return value});
}).then(function(value){
  console.log(value);
})
```

Comment: ugh - why wouldn't you just `return Promise.all(articles.map(article => {` *rest of code in question* - oh, wait, the code in the question uses `.map` like it was `.forEach` - never mind :p

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you change `someAsyncFunction` to return a promise, you could then call `articles.reduce` to call the function for each entry value and get an array of outstanding promises. Passing the array to `Promise.all` returns a single promise for successful completion, although the return promise will be rejected if any **single** operation fails. (I would hope  recent versions of Node.js support `Promise.all` by now).

The fulfilled value of `Promise.all` is a result array containing all the fulfilled values of the input promises. Hence you use the result array to set the the `content` property of entries in `articles` with matching index.

However, the initial number of outstanding promises is the same as the number of entries in `articles`. If this could be large or very large, you may not wish to initiate that many concurrent active asynchronous requests. A solution to this is to use "asynchronous" recursion to process asynchronous requests serially, one after the other.

There are 300 results for searching SO for "[javascript] asynchronous recursion", so I won't go into further detail here.